# Editable combobox not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have made a Editable Combobox which does filtering of items.

There are some problems which are numbered below.

1.) First Problem is that it works only for the very first time. For example for first time if I type B ,it shows me list of items starting with B. Then if i press Backspace and enter again B, then it shows me only first item in the list starting with B. This is the actual problem now. Below is link to my modified code.

2.) Second Problem is that i am not able to type a complete word in Combobox, it allows me to type only the 1st letter. And it shows me list of items matching it.

**XAML SIDE CODE**

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,104,0,0" Name="comboBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" PreviewTextInput="comboBox3_PreviewTextInput" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged"/>
```

**EVENT HANDLERS**

```
private void comboBox3_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;


    }

    private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((ComboBox)sender).Text != "")
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select p_id_pk,p_name FROM products", con);
            da.Fill(ds, "products");
            comboBox3.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "p_name like '" + ((ComboBox)sender).Text + "'+'%'";
            //comboBox3.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "p_name like 'B%'";
            comboBox3.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            comboBox3.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["p_name"].ToString();
            comboBox3.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["p_id_pk"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use following approach for performance reasons:

```
private DataSet ds = null; // initialize dataset with null value
private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ds == null) // initialize dataset on demand with all possible values from database
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select p_id_pk,p_name FROM products", con);
        da.Fill(ds, "products");

        comboBox3.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        comboBox3.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["p_name"].ToString();
        comboBox3.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["p_id_pk"].ToString();
        return;
    }

    // filter view based on text input
    ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "p_name like '"+ comboBox3.Text + "%'";
}
```

Comment: This is not answer of my problem.

Comment: Your Solution is Giving Error "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataSet"

Comment: @yaseenenterprises did you try it? You need to initialize ds in constructor.

Comment: Your original code is not working because of self invocation loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178718/discussion-between-yaseen-enterprises-and-dipen-shah).

Comment: You can post your code to public pastebin or github.

Comment: I have used same code which you have posted in a answer.

Comment: I initialized `DataSet`, check it now.

Comment: I have modified my code, it is working but problem is that it works only for the very first time. For example for first time if I type B it shows me list of items starting with B. Then if i press Backspace and enter again B, then it shows me only first item in the list starting with B. This is the actual problem now. 

Below is link to my modified code.  https://pastebin.com/dudX69QV

Comment: Now your Edited code is giving me this error "Cannot find table 0."

Comment: please help me . I am struggling to solve this problem since 1 month.

Comment: Put my edited code as it is, make sure as it is and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var searchtext = comboBox3.Text;
    comboBox3.ItemsSource = null;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select p_id_pk,p_name FROM products where p_name like '" + comboBox3.Text + "'+'%'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "products");
    comboBox3.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    comboBox3.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["p_name"].ToString();
    comboBox3.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["p_id_pk"].ToString();
    comboBox3.Text = searchtext;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by doing a simple change in XAML side. Now code in my question is properly working and WPF Simple combobox is transformed to Filtered Combobox.

I have basically set

```
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
```

to

```
      IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
```

and that has solved my problem which i was facing since 1 month or so.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,104,0,0" Name="comboBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" PreviewTextInput="comboBox3_PreviewTextInput" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Thanks to all who tried to help me.